# SageMaker DeepAR access data

Tags: machine-learning, amazon-ml

Can [SageMaker DeepAR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/deepar.html) algorithm only deal with training data that resides in Amazon S3 buckets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it appears to be so. Look [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/now-available-in-amazon-sagemaker-deepar-algorithm-for-more-accurate-time-series-forecasting/) for more details.
Here is a small, but important, extract:

> "Just like other Amazon SageMaker algorithms, it [deepAR] relies on Amazon
> Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) to store the training data and the
> resulting model."

Hope this helps.